# Replace values of a pandas Series from a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, series

Suppose I have a series `profile` that contains:

```
settings-win.data.microsoft.com    1
www.facebook.com                   0.4
clients4.google.com                1
plus.google.com                    0.86
```

And a list `new_val` that contains:

```
[0.8408964152537145, 0, 1.5, 0]
```

How do I replace all the values in my `profile` series with the list? It should be:

```
settings-win.data.microsoft.com    0.8408964152537145
www.facebook.com                   0
clients4.google.com                1.5
plus.google.com                    0
```

I tried the `.replace()` of `Series` but it doesn't seem to work.

**PS**. I'm also confused on how and when to use `.replace()` so if you could explain it further, it will be very appreciated.

Comment: `profile.values = new_val`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can create new `Series` with `index` of old `Series` `s` and values of list `li`:

```
print s
settings-win.data.microsoft.com    1.00
www.facebook.com                   0.40
clients4.google.com                1.00
plus.google.com                    0.86
Name: profile, dtype: float64

new_val = [0.8408964152537145, 0, 1.5, 0]
s1 = pd.Series(new_val, index=s.index, name='profile')

print s1
settings-win.data.microsoft.com    0.840896
www.facebook.com                   0.000000
clients4.google.com                1.500000
plus.google.com                    0.000000
Name: profile, dtype: float64
```

But maybe better is [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) or [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dictionary`, but result is different, because first and third value is same - [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html?highlight=map#applying-elementwise-python-functions):

```
d = {1: 0.8408964152537145, 0.4: 0, 0.86: 0}
print d
{1: 0.8408964152537145, 0.4: 0, 0.86: 0}

print s.replace(d)
settings-win.data.microsoft.com    0.840896
www.facebook.com                   0.000000
clients4.google.com                0.840896
plus.google.com                    0.000000
Name: profile, dtype: float64

print s.map(d)
settings-win.data.microsoft.com    0.840896
www.facebook.com                   0.000000
clients4.google.com                0.840896
plus.google.com                    0.000000
Name: profile, dtype: float64
```